# How to create a dockerfile that copies .tar and shell script?

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a image from postgresql and initialize it with a shell script for creating a database. So I have this .tar file which is a sample database file and in my docker file I'm copying this .tar file and shell script to the container but after building the image and running the container when I run that container in interactive mod there is no .tar file or shell script file inside it. What am I doing wrong?

This is my Dockerfile code.

```
FROM postgres:14-alpine
COPY ./dvdrental.tar dvdrental.tar
COPY ./entry.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-user-db.sh
```

Comment: Please include your build and run commands, and their output.

Comment: sudo docker build -t smp .

Comment: sudo docker run -d -p 5432:5432 --name smp -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password postgres